# Which exit code should I use for an international phone number on Amazon Japan?

Tags: amazon, phone-number

I'm sending a package from Amazon Japan to an address in China. In the phone number field in the contact information page, only numbers are accepted, not a plus sign `+`. Is it best to use the Chinese exit code `00`, the Japanese `010` or no exit code at all?

Comment: Crossposted at [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115550); I don't know which site is most appropriate to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

Its (worldwidely) common to use `00`.